# Bootstrap popover get stuck in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using bootstrap popover to render event in fullcalendar. It works fine displaying event detail when I'm hovering the event, but when I'm trying to resize the event, the popover created every time i resize the event and the popover getting stuck yet never fade out.
here is the screenshot

[popover stuck in event calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6D10.jpg)

and here is my eventRender code

```
 eventRender: function(event, element) {
                   $(element).popover({
                       title: 'Title: ' + event.title,
                       placement: 'right',
                       trigger: 'hover',
                       container: 'body',
                       html:true,
                       content: 'Start: ' + event.start.format("MMM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS") + '<br />End: ' + event.end.format("MMM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS") + '<br/>Description:' + event.description,
                   });
               },
```

If I remove the container attribute in popover it work fine in any condition but the popover display bounded by calendar row in month view. [bounded popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtny7.jpg)

Nb : I apologize for my poor english

Comment: Can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nzxyY/282/ . But i can't resize the event there. I don't know why. I've forked the code from another fiddle with some modification so the code look like my fullcalendar code in my project except the event source. I can't put my own code in jsfiddle cz  it's too complex to put in there. My fullcalender already have CRUD event with MySQL. Sorry it took me time to use jsfiddle. It's the first time I'm using it.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.

Answer (score 1):

For me @Angainor's answer does partially the job. Indeed when we have finished to resize, all the popovers disappear but during resize there still are multiple popovers. 
Here is how I managed to fix

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // Angainor's fix still needed
    $('.popover.fade.top').remove();
},
eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) { // Complementary to Angainor's fix
    $el.mousemove(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 1) {
            $('.popover.fade.top').remove();
        }
    }
},
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I post my solution to help future developers:

I destroy the popover in the "eventResize" function. It works well:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        $('.popover.fade.top').remove();
    },
...
```